# Update 'Active' Column to 'N' when a new record is inserted to table A

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have table A

```
FacilityID     CreatedDate       Active
---------------------------------------
   A001        2018-03-21          N
   A001        2018-03-22          Y
   A002        2018-03-21          Y
```

If a new FacilityID for A001 or A002 is inserted then the old record should become 'N'.

Can we achieve this with an `After Insert` trigger?

Formatted:

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[TableA_tr]
On [dbo].[Table A]
For INSERT
As
Begin
    Update [dbo].[Table A]
    Join 
    set [Active]='N'
    where [CreatedDate]<
```

Comment: IS this SQL Server?

Comment: Yes this is SQL server

Comment: Please see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE AFTER INSERT Trigger as you want to insert the new record:

```
 Create trigger [dbo].[TableA_tr]
    on [dbo].[Table A]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    --Update all records with the same facility id that do not match the datetime of the new item
    UPDATE [dbo].[TableA]
    SET Active = 'N'
    FROM    inserted INS
    JOIN    dbo.TableA AS T
            ON  T.row_id = INS.row_id;
    WHERE T.[FacilityId] = INS.FacilityId AND T.[CreatedDate] <> INS.CreatedDate

    GO
```

Comment: NO!!! You need to use a join to inserted. When you have scalar variables in your trigger it will not handle multiple row operations. This needs to be set based and it will become a good answer.

Comment: I didn't hear the poster ask about multiple row operations

Comment: It is a trigger. Not coding to handle multiple row operations is not the way to write triggers.

Comment: That's your opinion. Instead of complaining about my answer, offer a better solution with an answer of your own.

Comment: LOL and that of nearly anybody who has ever come across one of these. It is a simple fix. Also I think you have typo, you should update the table not the trigger. :)

Comment: I was going to give you a chance to fix this and let you get the rep. But ok, I will post a new answer.

Comment: @SeanLange Seriously, I have never had to worry about bulk inserts as the only triggers I have had to write were for applications that do singular updates and inserts, but I researched how to set it up for bulk inserts and updated my answer. This was my first time writing a trigger this way, so if you see anything else wrong with my answer above, please let me know.

Comment: Looks much better. Need aliases in the where predicates to avoid ambiguous error but you got the gist of it. Remember that just because an application does inserts one at a time it may not always function that way. And it would fail if there were data uploads of even two rows. Once you learn the set based trigger concept it is actually a lot simpler with less code. +1 from me.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for your input Sean. I appreciate it. Sorry if I got a little snippy at first, sometimes it is hard to decipher people's intent or attitude through text.

Comment: Stupid internet....you can't hear inflection. No worries mate. I was and am still only trying to help.

Comment: @SeanLange I get that. Thanks again. +1 From me as well.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach to this. This is set based and it will still work correctly if you insert 1 or any number of rows. Remember that in sql server triggers fire once per operation, not once per row like some other DBMS systems do.

```
Create trigger [dbo].[TableA_tr]
    on [dbo].[Table A]
    AFTER INSERT
    AS

    --Update all records with the same facility id that do not match the datetime of the new item
    UPDATE a
    SET Active = 'N'
    from dbo.TableA a
    join inserted i on i.FacilityId = a.FacilityId
                and i.CreatedDate <> a.CreatedDate
```